# Radio Button Check Control With Tab Pages

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a number of different tabs and within the tabs i have some radio buttons. I only want one radio button at a time within the tab pages to be selected. I have the following code

```
  private void RadioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
        var rdoButtonName = sender as RadioButton;
        foreach (TabPage page in pages)
        {
            foreach (Control item in page.Controls)
            {
                if (item is RadioButton)
                {
                    if (rdoButtonName.Name == item.Name)
                    {
                        rdoButtonName.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rdoButtonName.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i go to click on the radio buttons on the first tab page it does not allow me to change their checked status but it does on the other pages. Can anyone see anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: If you put them in a groupbox or other container you don't have to manually handle their Checked state.

Comment: @etaiso - it looks like he only wants one radio button selected across all tab pages

Comment: @Inkey - Are the radio buttons on the first tab page wired to the RadioButtonCheckedChanged handler?

Comment: @etaiso They are in group boxes. 

 Yes that is exactly what i need to achieve yes they all are linked to the RadioButtonCheckedChanged handler

Comment: @Inkey Are all of your RadioButtons CheckedChanged events attached with this code?

Comment: @etaiso they call the same event method

Comment: @Inkey Try my answer I think it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you set Cheked value to the sender and not to other radio buttons...

```
private void RadioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
    var rdoButtonName = sender as RadioButton;
    foreach (TabPage page in pages)
    {
        foreach (Control item in page.Controls)
        {
            if (item is RadioButton)
            {
                if (item.Name != rdoButtonName.Name)
                {
                    item.Checked = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (better debug and check) that your problem is that each time you change one of your RadioButton state it will call this function over again and will make the unexpected results.

To fix that I would detach and reattach your event handler before changing the `Checked` state, like this:

```
 private void RadioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
        var rdoButtonName = sender as RadioButton;
        foreach (TabPage page in pages)
        {
            foreach (Control item in page.Controls)
            {
                if (item is RadioButton)
                { 
                    rdoButtonName.CheckedChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.RadioButtonCheckedChanged);

                    if (rdoButtonName.Name == item.Name)
                    {
                        rdoButtonName.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rdoButtonName.Checked = false;
                    }

                    rdoButtonName.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.RadioButtonCheckedChanged);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does not work for when i debug it hits the rdoButtonName.Checked = true; and then it seems to uncheck it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that **"CheckedChanged"**-event can't be used in this kind of situation, and that is where the problem lies. The key is to use another event - **"Click"**:

```
    private void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TabPage page in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            foreach (RadioButton radioButton in page.Controls)
            {
                if (radioButton != (RadioButton)sender) { radioButton.Checked = false; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Change your RadioButtons to use this method in the **"Click"**-event and it'll work. I tested it myself.